# jquery queue dynamic addition of animations

Tags: jquery, queue

Here is the markup i have

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="eachFloor">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="floor"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="eachFloor">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="floor"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="eachFloor">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="floor"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="eachFloor">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="floor"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="eachFloor">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="floor"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="elevator"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the css i have

```
.container
{
width: 500px;
margin-left: 100px;
position:relative;
}

.floor
{
width: 400px;
background: #eee;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
height: 110px;
}

.elevator
{
background: #000;
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
left: 20px;
right: 20px;
width: 360px;
height: 75px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]
{
float:right;
margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

so as shown above i have a series of checkboxes when i click on one of them i should animate ( animate : top property ) and the div.elevator should go to the floor where the
checkbox is located and when i click on one of the checkboxes while the animation is running i should be able to check if the elevator has passed the currentfloor or not and if it has not passed the current floor i should stop the elevator in that particular floor for about a second or two and then proceed on with the previous animation.

Assume the elevator is in fifth (bottom) floor , so lets say i click on level 1 floor and then when the animation is running i click on level 3 floor and if the elevator has not passed the level 3 floor ( lets say it was in level 4 floor when i clicked the checkbox ) i should be able to stop the animate :top on the third floor for about a second or two and then continue on with the previous animation which is to the first floor ( from the third floor which is the current location of the elevator) .

if i put animate call like this

```
$(".container").on("click", "input:checkbox", function (event) {
  $(".elevator").animate({
    top: $(this).parent().offset().top
  }, {
    duration: 6000
  });
});
```

then the animation to the level 3 floor will happen only after it reaches the first floor so it will not stop in the middle ( reason being animations are queued on for the element). BUT HERE COMES THE POINT it can be done if i maintain the fx queue properly like when the level 1 floor checkbox is clicked i have the animate : top to level 1 floor and then when level 3 is clicked I NEED TO SOMEHOW MAGICALLY move 
the level 3 floor animation first in the queue ( if the floor has not passed and then stop the elevator there for about a second or two ) and then run the level 1 floor animation from level 3 floor.

How do i do this in jquery queue, clearQueue and other jquery methods ? i am ok if i need to use a plugin to pause / resume my animation too .... any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
$(function(){
     $(".container").on("click","input:checkbox",function(event){
         var pos = $(this).next().position().top;
         var elPos =  $(".elevator").position().top;
         $(".elevator").animate({marginTop: pos-elPos },6000);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vadXa/

Comment: thanks for your response john but where are you checking for my conditions mentioned in the question (ie what happens when you have aleady clicked on first floor and you again click 3rd floor but it will not stop in the third floor since the animations are queued ) ?  you are just worried about margin i believe. i will add the css i have to the question then it will make it clear.